# How do I get rid of error "unrecognized token: "#" " for a search query in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rails-console

This is the error I get:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "#": SELECT "posts"."id" AS
t0_r0, "posts"."title" AS t0_r1, "posts"."content" AS t0_r2, 
"posts"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "posts"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, 
"posts"."user_id" AS t0_r5, "posts"."course_id" AS t0_r6, 
"courses"."id" AS t1_r0, "courses"."name" AS t1_r1, 
"courses"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "courses"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, 
"courses"."major_id" AS t1_r4, "courses"."user_id" AS t1_r5 FROM 
"posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = 
"posts"."course_id" WHERE (courses.name IN (#{s},#{s}))  ORDER BY 
posts.created_at DESC
```

For this query:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:course).where("courses.name IN (#{@user.courses.map(&:name).collect { |s| '#{s}'  }.join(',') })").references(:courses).order("posts.created_at DESC")
```

I dont understand why #{s} doesn't become the strings in the array

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your problem is that string interpolation does not work inside single quotes. You need to use `"#{s}"`.

However, as a first improvement, the preferred method of converting a variable to a string is simply to call `s.to_s`. That said, `name` sounds like it's *already* a string, so the entire process of mapping can probably be eliminated.

You also should not be using string interpolation to build a query. Use parameterized queries, give Rails the array of strings, and let it do the work for you:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:course).where('courses.name IN (?)', @user.courses.pluck(:name))
```

Note that, to select a single column from a set of results, it's **tremendously** faster to use `pluck(:field)` than `map(&:field)`. The `map` method selects all the columns, instantiates entire ActiveRecord models for the result, and then throws out all that effort when you reduce the collection down to the single field. `pluck` *only* selects the required field, and doesn't build AR objects for the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer really helped, I had an issue with string iterpolation, the code that worked is

```
@posts = Post.all.includes(:course).where("courses.name IN (#{@user.courses.map(&:name).collect { |s| "'#{s}'"  }.join(',') })").references(:course).order("posts.created_at DESC")
```